# Infinite scroll loads new posts several times

Tags: theme-development, plugin-jetpack

I've added [infinite scroll support](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/) of the Jetpack plugin to my own theme with:

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container'  => 'content',
    'footer' => false,
    'render' => 'vividflow_infscroll_render',
    'wrapper' => false,
    'posts_per_page' => 12
) );
```

The `vividflow_infscroll_render` just loads The Loop.

However, I'm experiencing some trouble with the infinite scroll: new posts are loaded **multiple times**, so that I get **double posts** on the archive page. My archive page looks like this:

[image]

I think new posts are loaded several times because I have several posts on the bottom line: 3. When I place all the post summaries beneath each other, there is no problem.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: n/p. Figured it out, improved the question and now let's clean up the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indeed was that there were several posts on the bottom. Adding this to the end of the loop helped:

```
<br style="clear:both;"/>
```

I think this is a bug in the Jetpack plugin, but it is easily resolved by adding this line break.